# Как отключить сигнализирование об ошибках в VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Подскажите пожалуйста как в VS Code отключить надоедливую сигнализацию об ошибках типа "Свойство объявлено, но его значение не было прочитано", а именно выделение и подчеркивание волнистой линией, которая стала появляться предположительно после установки мной определенных npm пакетов (видимо изменились настройки eslint)? Вполне устраивал предыдущий вариант индикации, когда  просто такая переменная становилась блеклой.

Comment: Вам нужно настроить `eslint`. Вы можете перейти по ссылке (выделено синим в подсказке) и увидеть, как это можно настроить.

Comment: Пытался: безуспешно, ни очень понимаю каким образом в итоге исключить это правило. Вроде бы нужно вставить правило:
 {
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": "warn"
  }
},
но вот куда и каким образом - мрак (

Comment: У вас в корне есть файл `.eslintrc`?

Comment: Если в корне проекта - нет.